# Finding users with two or more roles discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'll post my entire code because on other forums people were confused:

I am trying to make a discord bot that can display a list of users that have a specific role. I know I need to list all roles in an array and then compare the user inputs to see if they match the strings in the array. Then it will check for users who have all of the user input roles and display them.

Example: if Spookybot and SpookySeed both have the role of admin but only Spookybot has the role of moderator as well, if i type role admin moderator the result should only display Spookybot since he has both roles. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

```
const Discord = require ('discord.js')
const { MessageEmbed } = require ('discord.js')
const { type } = require('os')
const { receiveMessageOnPort } = require('worker_threads')
const client = new Discord.Client()

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("Connected as " + client.user.tag)

    client.user.setActivity("you senpai!", {type: "LISTENING"})
})

client.on('message', (receivedMessage) => {
    if (receivedMessage.author == client.user) {
        return
    }
    if (receivedMessage.content.startsWith("``")) {
        processCommand(receivedMessage)
    }
})

function processCommand(receivedMessage) {
    let fullCommand = receivedMessage.content.substr(2)
    let splitCommand = fullCommand.split(" ")
    let primaryCommand = splitCommand[0]
    let argument = splitCommand.slice(1)

    if (primaryCommand == "help") {
        helpCommand(argument, receivedMessage)
    }
    else if (primaryCommand == "role") {
            roleDisplayCommand(argument, receivedMessage)
    } 
    else {
        receivedMessage.channel.send("Uknown command")
    }
}

function helpCommand(argument, receivedMessage) {
    if (arguments.length > 0) {
        receivedMessage.channel.send("It looks like you might need help with but i am still in beta sorry!")
    } else {
        receivedMessage.channel.send("Unknown command")
    }
}

function roleDisplayCommand(arguments, receivedMessage) {
    if (arguments.length > 0) {
        const roleNames = receivedMessage.content.split(" ").slice(1);

        receivedMessage.author.send(`These users have the ${roleNames.join(" ")} role(s)` )
        
        const userList = roleNames.map(roleName => receivedMessage.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === roleName).members.map(m=>m.user.tag).join("\n"))
        
        const sortedList = userList.join().split(",").filter((item, index, self) => self.indexOf(item) === index);
        receivedMessage.author.send(sortedList.join("\n"))
        
    }
     else {
        receivedMessage.channel.send("Unknown command")
    }
}
client.login("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Try to keep your code snippets more concise and only include the relevant part for the question, in this case I think just the `roleDisplayCommand` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter on your guild users list:

```js
const specificsUsers = users.filter(user =>
    user.roles.has(role1.id) && user.roles.has(role2.id)
)
```

Comment: I suppose he wants this for any amount of roles so you'd have to iterate the roles and filter out the ones that don't have it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd iterate over the roles and filter out the users without the roles. Something like this should work.

```js
function roleDisplayCommand(arguments, receivedMessage) {
    ...
    const roleNames = receivedMessage.content.split(" ").slice(1);

    receivedMessage.author.send(`These users have the ${roleNames.join(" ")} role(s)` )
       
    let users = receivedMessage.guild.members.cache;
    const userList = roleNames.every(
      role => {
        users = users.filter(u => u.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === role));
      });

    // Either
    receivedMessage.author.send(Array.from(users.values()).join("\n"));
    // or, but not tested and might have some weird behaviors
    receivedMessage.author.send(Array.prototype.join.call(users, "\n"));
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried out your code and it gave me a TypeError saying that users.filter is not a function

Comment: urgh, it's a `GuildCollectionManager`, I wrote this off the top of my head. Use the cache instead which is a collection. (edited accordingly).

Comment: I hate to do this too you and I REALLY APPRECIATE the help but it got another Type error saying ``u.role.has`` is not a function

Comment: That's what I get for writing code off the top of my head in a browser without type indications. It's another manager and again, you'll need to cache instead, a bit different than what I've wrote, I'll edit.

Comment: TypeError: u.roles.cache.any is not a function with this new code snippet

Comment: It's `some` in js.

Comment: OMG i feel so bad but one last question I got a type error for this ``TypeError: users.join is not a function``

Comment: Didn't realise Discord.js `Collection` doesn't have a `join` method. I'll write 2 alternatives.

Comment: OMG YESSSSS IT WORKS THANK YOU! The first option was correct

Comment: I think i actually celebrated to early. I typed ``role admin member`` and Spookybot still appeared on the list even though he is only a member not an admin as well :/